# Unable to get MariaDB 10.1 (on centos 7) to listen only on IPv4

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, ipv4, galera

How could I get MariaDB 10.1 to listen only on IPv4? Strange but true the very first time I installed MariaDB and started it, I saw that it was correctly listening on IPv4 as shown in the example picture below

[image]

But strangely after reinstalling MariaDB for some reasons and rebooting my Centos 7 installation, it seems to have started listening only on IPv6 and I hence I cannot get the Galera Cluster to work (which was working fine when it was listening on IPv4). So how do I get this MariaDB to listen only on IPv4. The below is a screenshot from my machine

```
[root@dataqry-0001 ~]# netstat -ntpl | grep sql
tcp6 0      0 :::3306                 :::*          LISTEN      14323/mysqld
```

Contents of /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf (Pls note that I also tried uncommenting out the bind address, it is still the same strangely)

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

I should add that I am quite confused with MariaDB / MySQL settings littered all over the place. The above bind-address is for Galera I guess. It's my first time with MariaDB on Centos 7, so apologies - I even tried disabling IPv6 earlier but doesn't show it listening on IPv4

Thanks
M.M

Comment: Can you post your `my.ini` . I want to check the value on `bind-address`

Comment: Thanks Hackerman, I added the .cnf file to the OP. There are a bunch of .cnf files in the /usr/share/mysql. Could it be the mysql.server file or something you are referring to?

Comment: My mistake, it should be `my.cnf`, and it's available on `/etc/my.cnf`...so just try `less /etc/my.cnf`...or maybe you post the right file, you can try uncommenting this line `#bind-address=0.0.0.0`(just remove the `#` and restart the server

Answer (score 2):

**Preface**

Although the information in the official MariaDB bug-tracker seems to suggest that this is not possible, unless the `mysql` software is used instead; I can confirm that setting the following configuration option in e.g. `/etc/my.cnf`, at least while using version `10.1.21-MariaDB`, **does** work as expected and as outlined in @Hackerman's comment.

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

The misunderstood/misleading/irrelevant official bug-trackers I eluded to:

- [MDEV-6536](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6536) (Open)
- [MDEV-4379](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-4379) (Closed)

---

**Answer**

To answer the question as it pertains to your specific scenario, however, you should pay attention to the "*section*" under which that setting is set; namely, you have it written under the `[galera]` section, rather than the server-wide `[mysqld]` section.

```
[mysqld]

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Make sure `bind-address` is specified in the `[mysqld]` section.